# Identifying overlapping rows in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, inner-join, concatenation

I have two dataframes like

df1

```
Time      accler
19.13.33  24
19.13.34  24
19.13.35  25
19.13.36  27
19.13.37  25
19.13.38  27
19.13.39  25
19.13.40  24
```

df2

```
 Time      accler
19.13.29  24
19.13.30  24
19.13.31  25
19.13.32  27
19.13.33  25
19.13.34  27
19.13.35  25
19.13.36  24
```

These two data frames overlap over column time from 19.13.33 to 19.13.36. So when ever there is a overlap  I wanted only the dataframe which consists of the overlapped rows

expected output

df1

```
 Time      accler
19.13.33  24
19.13.34  24
19.13.35  25
19.13.36  27
```

df2

```
Time      accler
19.13.33  25
19.13.34  27
19.13.35  25
19.13.36  24
```

or I can also have a `concat` of the dataframes which will be helpful for further processing.

I tried `merge` but did not work as the dataframes are created dynamically depending on the number of csv files. I tried concatenating first all the dataframes and tried to iterate over the rows but did not find a way.

Comment: try inner join on 'Time' column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), default parameter `how='inner'` can be omited:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time')
print (df)
       Time  accler_x  accler_y
0  19.13.33        24        25
1  19.13.34        24        27
2  19.13.35        25        25
3  19.13.36        27        24

df1 = df[['Time','accler_x']].rename(columns={'accler_x':'accler'})
print (df1)
       Time  accler
0  19.13.33      24
1  19.13.34      24
2  19.13.35      25
3  19.13.36      27

df2 = df[['Time','accler_y']].rename(columns={'accler_y':'accler'})
print (df2)
       Time  accler
0  19.13.33      25
1  19.13.34      27
2  19.13.35      25
3  19.13.36      24
```

If you need `merge` multiple `DataFrames` use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
#Python 3
import functools

df = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x.merge(y,on=['Time']), [df1, df2])

#python 2
df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.merge(y,on=['Time']), [df1, df2])
```

Comment: I tried using merge but i am getting repetition of column values

Comment: Problem is your values are duplicated. Is possible remove duplicated rows by column `Time` ?

Comment: actually my data is samples that are recorded from mobile phone .I am collecting 10 samples per second. So if I am merging I am getting 30 samples.

Comment: I add solution for merging multiple Dataframes, please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day and thank you for accepting!

Comment: regarding the same question is there a way of getting the desired output without using merge because there might be more multiple dataframes. Is it possible that initially I concat all the dataframes and then check for any overlap without using merge function.

Comment: It will be works if in each `DataFrame` are not duplicates rows. Then you can use `concat` and then select all duplicates rows. But then get only rows which overlapping is some 2 dataframes, but not in all DataFrames. Is it possible?

Comment: Ya it is fine as there is no need that all the dataframes should overlap.

Comment: You can try `df = pd.concat([df1,df2])` and 
`df = df[df.duplicated(subset='Time')]` - You get all values which are duplicates - overlapped. Please check it.

Comment: It means not all dataframes has same column names, I think. You can check it by `for df in [df1,df2,dfn]: print (df.columns.tolist())`